# Do mobile phones lower their radiation if connected to WIFI

Tags: wifi, mobile, radiation

Suppose you have a phone you use for surfing, but the coverage is poor. As far as I know, that means it would have to increase its signal strength to max, quite possibly to a signal strength much stronger han a WIFI access-point.

Now suppose the mobile was connected to a WIFI close to it, the communicaiton with the mobile tower should be eliminated with regards to internet traffic and hence the mobile would no longer need to increase its signal to max.

However, the mobile would still need to be in contact with its tower to take incoming calls and text messages. So my question is if routing a mobile internet traffic through WIFI would make a mobile lessen its signal strength or amount? (A least compared to when surfing.) I imagine this behavior may also be dependent on he mobile phone model, but if anyone happens to know, it would be great.

(The one who gave this a minus one - could you please explain where this question would be better to post to get an answer?)

Comment: Off-topic but mobile/cell phones don't radiate much energy when listening for incoming calls/messages compared to when transmitting voice/data. You'd have to measure WiFi radiated energy vs GSM radiated energy in your specific location to measure which is "better".

Comment: I have upvoted your comment. I am not sure I understand how the question could be offtopic given the naming, taglines and other similar questions, but I am new to this exchange, so I guess I will just have to accept it even if it seemed spot-on to me :) Anyhow, I got an answer to my question for which I am very happy. If anyone can point out a more appropriate exchange for similar electronics/electrical related questions (radio? just figured there could be specifics with regarding to mobiles not known there), I will be happy to post there in the future!

Comment: No big deal but *"[Electronics.Stackexchange is not about consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"* Your Q seems to me more about **using** existing consumer products than **designing** new electronics.

Comment: @Tom - www.piclist.com (don't be scared off by the PIC part - it's eclectic). Subscription information at bottom of page. 
Joinn. No spam etc - registration just controls the spammers (somewhat) and you can unsubscribe anytime. Post a "hello world" post with tag [EE] in subject line and ask your question. 0 or more people will answer, many may, I may, ...  :-). | It's a mailing list type forum for all things electronic and technical with a PIC focused core but a 'cloud' of much else. Complements Stack Exchange. Essentially anything electronic is allowed (and much else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're far from the tower, the phone will turn its GSM/3G TX power up regardless of whether it's on wifi or not.

*However*, if it's on wifi, then the only GSM/3G transmission that will happen at that high power is the periodic commuication to remind the tower where the phone is. The TX will be turned off almost all the time.